# WHERE condition on new created Column in Impala

Tags: sql, impala, qsqlquery

In my Table, I have time information in UNIX time that I have converted to the proper time format using the following function in impala:
`cast(ts DIV 1000 as TIMESTAMP) as NewTime.`

Now I want to apply WHERE query on the newly created column "NewTime" to select the data from a particular time period but I am getting the following error:

```
"Could not revolve column/field reference: NewTime".
```

How can I apply WHERE query on the newly created column in impala.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use an alias defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` for that `SELECT`.  Repeat the expression, use a CTE, or use a subquery.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate it using inner subquery and then use it for filtering.

```
select NewTime
from 
(select cast(ts DIV 1000 as TIMESTAMP) as NewTime,... from table) subq
where 
subq.NewTime >now()
```

You can also use CTE like Gordon said.